# How to create dynamic tables in google bigquery dataset and access in tableau?

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

I have a BigQuery database, i want to create dynamic tables.

Ex: table_20170609 - *if date is 9th june 2017*
    table_20170610 - *if date is 10th june 2017*

Daily i will get some excel data and i have to upload to the above dynamically created table. Data in excel is not day wise, it will be from start date to today's date.

I know connecting bigquery to tableau and running queries. Is there any automated method where tableau will read dynamic table from bigquery and generate the report.

current working -  i have created one table(reports) and everyday i will rename the table reports to reports_bkp_date and will create new table reports.

I'm new to bigquery and tableau, i would like to know -
**How to create dynamic tables in bigquery?**
**How to connect dynamic table to tableau (daily i should not change table name manually)?**

Comment: I don't quite get what you're trying to achieve, but sounds like partitioned tables might help here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables. Instead of creating one table per day you create a partition per day.

Answer (score 1):

You have two immediate options - firstly, create a view in BigQuery (instead of a table) which will collate together all relevant tables, then connect to this in Tableau.

The better approach, given that you are having to manually upload a new table every day, is to use a wildcard table connection in Tableau and use a similar naming convention for your data tables, for example you might use **DailyData_2017_*** to capture all tables in he following format:

**DailyData_2017_06_01**

**DailyData_2017_06_02**

**DailyData_2017_06_03**

Finally, note that you can append to a table in BigQuery, rather than replacing it's contents. If your data is time stamped then this might work for you too.

Ben

Comment: Thanks Ben. Right now i'm getting data from start date to today. I dont want to connect other tables in tableau. Only i want to connect the table with current date from bigquery to tableau.

Comment: In this case I would make a view that shows the data from today and connect to your view in Tableau. Hope that helps, Ben.

Comment: If i use views then i cannot create bigquery job that exports data from a view